# Use Outlook dialer to dial Google voice?

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2003, google-voice

How can I use Outlook dialer to dial Google Voice? This is for "over the web", not through a modem.

This way I can track my calls on Outlook.

Comment: Not sure about using Outlook to dial Google voice, but have you taken a look at Outlook's [Journal](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/managing-calls-HA001123154.aspx) feature?

Comment: Yeah, I know. That's what gets activated as part of the dialer. Thanks.

Comment: Have you also taken a look at this [article](http://tech.navarr.me/2010/04/using-google-voice-with-outlooks-dialer.html)? [Clamr](http://www.clamr.com/about-clamr/) also allows you to do this, but requires Outlook 2010

Comment: After setting up the account as directed in CLAMR, I have discovered that I need a Google Voice number. Apparently I cannot get on as I am in Canada. So great though this info is, it does not answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are connected via modem, then there is a free solution, described here :
[Using Google Voice with Outlook’s Dialer](http://tech.navarr.me/2010/04/using-google-voice-with-outlooks-dialer.html#more-447).

For calling over the web, there is an easier commercial solution at [Clamr!](http://www.clamr.com/), described more in detail in :
[Make calls directly from Outlook 2010 with Google Voice!](http://stormer.us.com/general/email/make-calls-directly-from-outlook-2010-with-google-voice/).
Subscription cost is 30$ per year, with a 7-day trial.

Comment: I haven't noticed that Clamr doesn't support Outlook 2003. It may be worthwhile to ask their Sales about it.

Comment: It's for web calling. I'll edit my question. Thanks. I will try Clamr today. I have Outlook 2003.

Comment: After setting up the account as directed in CLAMR, I have discovered that I need a Google Voice number. Apparently I cannot get on as I am in Canada. So great though this info is, it does not answer my question. Plus 1.

Comment: The commercial solution requires Outlook 2010.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer. It answers the basic question, and I just don't qualify for the full Google Voice, at least at this time as I'm in Canada. Thanks.

Comment: You could maybe use a free proxy to "move" yourself to another country, although free proxies are rarely of good quality. Remark: acceptance of the answer and awarding the bounty are 2 separate actions.